# Can I treat size_t as a void pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I am working with an external library that is storing `void*` inside of a queue. For example,

```
void queue_insert(Queue* queue, void* data);
```

However, I want to store `size_t` data inside the queue instead. I can't pass the address of the `size_t` data (because it's locally scoped). I never need to access the data again, though.

In other words, I will be calling these functions

```
queue_insert(queue, 5);
bool exists = queue_contains(queue, 5);
```

but I will never be doing the following (because it doesn't make sense)

```
void* p = queue_pop(queue);
size_t s = *p;
```

With that being said, can I pass `size_t` variables to a function that takes a `void*`?

Comment: "can I pass size_t variables to a function that takes a void*" -->  The conversion from one to the other may lose information.  sdasdadas, is that OK for your application?  How portable does the code need to be?

Comment: Not with complete portability, you can't, but on many implementations it may be documented or accepted practice.

Comment: Losing information probably won’t work for me. Does it lose information even if the two types are the same size or is that implementation defined? Am I better to look into using uintptr_t somehow?

Comment: sdasdadas, `size_t` --> `void *` --> `size_t` is not specified in C to return the original `size_t`.  It _might_ work for some values, might not.

Comment: `uintptr_t` won't help you here; it's guaranteed that you can store a pointer in a `uintptr_t` and get it back, but not the other way around.  AFAIK the only way to get this with complete portability is to `malloc` space for your `size_t`, store the pointer, and free it later.

Comment: The code itself does not need to be portable. I am running Ubuntu with gcc. Should I be investigating gcc’s documentation for this?

Comment: @NateEldredge `void *` --> `uintptr_t` --> `void *` is specified to result in an _equivalent_ pointer, but not certainly the same bit pattern.  Your `malloc()` idea is good.

Comment: With gcc I believe you are safe, so long as `void *` is larger than `size_t` (which I am pretty sure will be the case).  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Arrays-and-pointers-implementation.html#Arrays-and-pointers-implementation

Comment: Thank you both very much. This code is throwaway so I will use it as a temporary fix if it appears to work.

Comment: Your external library is specified as dealing in `void *` pointers because it *wants you* to dynamically allocate the data structures it's managing for you.  If you don't want to do that, if you want to manage smaller, simpler, non-allocated data structures like a single value of type `size_t`, you should seriously look for a different queue management library that gives you that flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, when a general-purpose library offers algorithms such as queue management, sorting, spawning threads, and so on, a `void *` parameters essentially means “I will take a handle to anything you want. Just put it in memory and give me a pointer to it. I will give you the pointer back when you need it.”

This is often used with a structure. Need to manage job information passed to a thread, like starting and ending indices, configuration parameters, and more? Define a structure type, allocate memory for it, pass the address of the memory for the library’s `void *` parameter. But it can also be used with a scalar item too.

To pass a `size_t`, use `malloc` to allocate space for the `size_t`, put the value in the allocated space, and pass the address to `queue_insert`.

When you are popping an element, use `size_t *s = queue_pop(queue);`. Then `*s` is the `size_t` you stored. When you are doing with it, free the memory with `free(s)`.

Comment: This is how I normally use them and it works fine. However, I am running a loop that generates new structs on each iteration. These structs are malloc'ed and destroyed at the beginning and end of each iteration. There are functionally equivalent structs that have different pointer references. Really, I'm wishing the library had a custom comparison operator for `void*` entries.